# Lazy loading proxy also loads entity from database while accessing primary identifier

Tags: doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, proxy-classes

I'm using `$entityManager->getReference()` to get a proxy for my entity. When I call the getter for the primary key Doctrine will intialize the proxy and execute a SELECT query. I expect this only to happen when calling other properties which are not yet known by Doctrine.

The code below illustrates the issue:

```
$myEntity = $em->getReference('MyNamespace\MyEntity', 1);
$myEntity->getId(); //This will execute a database call. I expect it to just return 1
```

The getter in the lazy loading proxy looks like this:

```
public function getId()
{

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getId', array());

    return parent::getId();
}
```

Is this intended behaviour or did I overlook something?

Comment: Works as designed.  In most cases you will use the reference object itself.  You already know the id.

Comment: Yes I know the ID of course, but I'm passing around entities in my domain, this is what you want from an OOP perspective. My consuming classes need to be unaware of the Proxy and persistance (db) related code (handle a fully hydrated entity the same as a proxy).

Comment: Yep.  But in an ORM system, the id is only used for persistence.  Thus, your consuming classes should not be calling getId() in the first place.